# Show that series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(\theta n)/n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to show that series  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\theta n)}{n}$$ converges for except $\theta=0  ,2\pi$.

I understand that I should use Dirichlet test as $1/n \to0$ , and intuitively I know that I can bound  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\cos(\theta n)$ for all $N$ since cos is bounded but I could not do it.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can complete your argument by noting that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\cos (n\theta )}  = \Re \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {e^{in\theta } }  = \Re \frac{{e^{i\theta }  - e^{i(N + 1)\theta } }}{{1 - e^{i\theta } }} = \frac{{\sin \left( {\left( {N + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\theta } \right)}}{{2\sin \left( {\frac{\theta }{2}} \right)}} - \frac{1}{2}
$$ if $0<\theta<2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step one: Find a formula for $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a^i}{i}.$$
Step two: see what happens when $a = \exp(i \theta).$

Step three: Note that your series is the real part of the above.

Step four: Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to
use complex numbers,
you can do this:

Since

$\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b)
=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)
-(\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b))\\
=2\cos(a)\sin(b)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sin(t/2)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\cos(t n)
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\sin(t/2)\cos(t n)\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}(\sin(tn+t/2)-\sin(tn-t/2))/2\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}(\sin(t(2n+1)/2)-\sin(t(2n-1)/2))/2\\
&=\dfrac12(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\sin(t(2n+1)/2)-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\sin(t(2n-1)/2))\\
&=\dfrac12(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\sin(t(2n+1)/2)-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}\sin(t(2n+1)/2))\\
&=\dfrac12(\sin(t(2N+1)/2)-\sin(t/2))\\
\end{array}
$